# $\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2{\pi z}}$ partial fraction decomposition

Tags: complex-analysis

My teacher has proved in class the following theorem. (I'm sorry but I don't know a book in which this theorem appears.)

> Given $f$ meromorphic in $\mathbb{C}$ and a sequence of squares $C_n$ with center $0$ and side $2r_n$ so that $f$ don't have poles in the boundary of $C_n$ for any $n$.
>
> $\mathcal{P}$ is the set of poles of $f$ including the point $0$, and $S_a$ is the principal part of each pole $a\in\mathcal{P}$ (if $0$ is not a pole we take $S_0=0$).
>
> Suppose there is a sequence $(\varepsilon_n)_n$ of positive real numbers with $\varepsilon_n\to 0$ when $n\to\infty$, and there exists an integer $p\geq -1$ so that $|f(z)|\leq \varepsilon_n |z|^{p+1}$ for $z$ in the boundary of $C_n$.
>
> Then,
>
> - If $p=-1$ we have $f(z)=\lim\limits_n\sum\limits_{a\in\mathcal{P}\cap C_n}S_a(z)$
> - If $p>-1$ we have $f(z)=\lim\limits_n\sum\limits_{a\in\mathcal{P}\cap C_n}[S_a(z)-P_a(z)]$ where $P_a$ is the Taylor polynomial in $0$ of degree $p$ of $S_a$ if $a\not=0$ and of $S_0-f$ if $a=0$.

I want to apply this theorem to prove that $$\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2{\pi z}}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac1{(z-n)^2}.$$

I use squares with side of length $2(n+\frac12)$, so there are not poles in the boundary of the squares. I have concluded that $p=-1$ is not possible but $p=0$ is possible. In that case, the polynomial $P_a$ of the theorem is $\frac1{n^2}$ for $n\not=0$ and $0$ for $n=0$. Thus, I have an extra term $\frac{1}{n^2}$. Can somebody help me? What's wrong in my argument? Thank you!

Comment: Here the theorem is that $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac1{(z-n)^2}$ converges to a meromorphic function and $f(z)=\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2{\pi z}}-\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac1{(z-n)^2}$ is a $2$-periodic entire function bounded on $\Re(z) \in [0,2]$, thus $f$ is constant. Since $f(i\infty ) = 0$ then $f(z)=0$.

Comment: The theorem requires taking the coefficient $c_0$ in the expansion of
$$\frac 1 {z^2} - \frac {\pi^2} {\sin^2 \pi z}$$
around zero. $c_0 \neq 0$.

Comment: Yes! That solves the problem. The coefficient is $c_0=-\frac{\pi^2}{3}$ and disappears with the $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac2{n^2}$. Thank you very much